# How can I centre a div dynamically to where my page is and make the page 'disabled' when the div shows?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to do that when a `button` is pressed, it will display a `div` in the middle of the page no matter where my page is, it can be on the bottom part or top part of the page and still it would be in the middle.
I'm using `position: absolute` because I need it to be 'floating' above other elements.

I searched everywhere and didn't see how to do it. Only in the middle, but not 'dynamically'.

Also, how can I make the rest of the page that is behind the `div` disabled?

my current css:

```
#buyComponentTesting{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26%;
    left: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested, it should be `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`. Please avoid other CSS written for demo.

```css
.page{
  pointer-events:none;//page disabled
 /*Not required for this solution*/
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
/*Not required for this solution*/  
}

#buyComponentTesting{
  position:fixed;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  top:calc(50% - 50px);
  left:calc(50% - 50px);
  pointer-events:all; /*but the div is accessible*/
  
  /*Not required for this solution*/
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  background:beige;
  cursor:pointer;
  /*Not required for this solution*/
}

#buyComponentTesting:hover{
    border-color:#333;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div id="buyComponentTesting">The DIV</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I make it, that the wanted div that should be  displayed is above the opacity? I did that it kinda covers the page with white page, with opacity of 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

```
#buyComponentTesting{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

The code above will center the div. top and left will move the upper right corner of the div to the center of the page but to actually have the div sit in the center we would need to move if left by its width / 2 and up by its height / 2 which is done with transform property.

Also you cloud center the div horizontally use `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)`;
Note: Code above has `position: fixed` to have the div appear even when scrolling.

To have the rest of the page "disabled" as You mentioned, one option would be to create an overlay with fixed or absolute position which will sit above all element except for the `div`. You can either use `::before` selector or separate element to create overlay

```
div::before, .overlay{
   content: ""; //Add this property only when using ::before or ::after, otherwise they won't be displayed
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 80; /*Less then z-index of the div*/
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the part of the disabled, it painted the screen all black, before I even rendered the component that should disable the rest. Im working with ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`. 
From below code, this is will be show in the middle.

```
#buyComponentTesting {
                background-color: blue;
                z-index: 999;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
```

But If you want to create like popup than use this

```css
.container {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 999;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    
    #buyComponentTesting {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="buyComponentTesting">
  </div>
</div>
```

I think, it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#buyComponentTesting{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin : auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Please try the above code share your feedback